# String use python to print?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Use of string to print ?

```
St="hello to all my friends in python"
Print (St[1:3:-1])
```

> IT print blank

Comment: What's the problem are you facing?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: please edit your question to provide clear information. Right now it is hard to understand what you are trying to say

Comment: [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 0):

In print function you're slicing the string from 1st index to less than 3rd index. But you're using a negative step (which means reverse). So it won't print anything. If you use positive step then it will print `el`.
Here is the corrected code:

```
print(St[1:3:1])
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are reversing the string (-1 in the slicing), you should also treat the elements of the string reversed, so 3 comes before 1. Try the following:

```
print(St[3:1:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
s = "hello to all my friends in python"
print(s[1,2])
```